# Is there a way to add optional query parameter to selected (or all) Actions without specifying it explicitly during Action definition in Controller

Tags: scala, playframework

```
class Ctrl extends Controller {
  def action1(parameter: Option[Boolean]) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  ...

  def action2(parameter: Option[Boolean]) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  ...
}
```

is there a way to specify that e.g. all `Actions` defined in this `Ctrl` can deal with optional query `parameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read it from the query string on each action:

```
request.queryString.get("param1").flatMap(_.headOption)
```

Or create a function to read it:

```
class ApplicationController extends ... {
   ...
   // define it once in the controller (or in a trait that the controller extends)
   def param1 (implicit r: RequestHeader): Option[String] = 
     request.queryString.get("param1").flatMap(_.headOption)
   ...


   def action1 () = Action.async {implicit request =>
     // use it here now
     param1 // Option[String]

     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using

```
req.queryString.get(name).flatMap(_.headOption)
```

Get the query param using name in every action and create an output based on the optional param. But the problem with this method is code duplication. You have to do this in every action.

There is a way to do this using Action composition without code duplication. Create custom action which reads the required param from the queryParams of the request. Now you can use the custom action to get access to `Option[String]` which is the param if at all the user has sent it in the request url.

*QueryPramAction.scala*

```
trait QueryParamAction {
  self: Controller =>

  def withQueryParamAction(f: Option[String] => Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result], name: String = "param") = Action.async { req =>
    f(req.queryString.get(name).flatMap(_.headOption))(req)
  }

}
```

*ApplicationController.scala*

```
class ApplicationController @Inject() () extends Controller with QueryParamAction {

  def doStuff = withQueryParamAction { paramOpt => req =>
    Future.successful(Ok(s"got a param $paramOpt"))
  }

}
```

*routes*

```
GET   /dostuff   controllers.ApplicationController.doStuff
```

*Request*

```
http://localhost:9000/dostuff?param=hello
```

*Output*

```
got a param Some(hello)
```

If you don't need an option instead if you need a param every time then change the implementation of the CustomParamAction trait as given below

```
trait QueryParamAction {
  self: Controller =>

  def withQueryParam(f: String => Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result], name: String = "param") = Action.async { req =>
    req.queryString.get(name).flatMap(_.headOption).map(f(_)(req)).getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest(s"need a param with name: $name")))
  }

}
```

Now you will get BadRequest if you don't send the param in the url